# How to reset CSS if user scrolls up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following script:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    $("#reas").fadeIn(2000);
                    $(".footer").fadeIn(2000);
                    $(".master_footer").css("position", "relative");
                }
            });
```

The script above changes the position of .master_footer if the user scrolls below #reas.  But when i go up the position for .master_footer remains at relative.  What can I do to reset it to position:absolute when the user scrolls back up?

Comment: You've got code that sets the "position" to "relative"; can't you just add code to set it back to "fixed" or "absolute"?

Comment: i am new to js don't know how to go that far.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've set the css for the `.master_footer` element previous to setting it with the javascript: in your javascript, when you want to reset the element back to its default style, just remove the `style` attribute from the element:

`$(".master_footer").removeAttr("style");`

for example:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        $("#reas").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".footer").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".master_footer").css("position", "relative");
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 500){ // <-- set your reset point here
        $(".master_footer").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

where you would set the `else if` statement to whatever point you wanted to reset your element at.

Comment: how do i create a reset function?

Comment: I mean reset in the sense of setting another conditional that will fire once you scroll back up a certain amount, or past a certain point, much like you have already.

Comment: master_footer originally is set to fixed.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the position is set to; when your javascript applies the css to the content, it adds it as an attribute of the html. Once you reach your desired place on the page via scroll, you can remove the attribute and the element will read the original css you had set it up as

Comment: ok i used it but it's not consistent.  the master_footer disappears and when i scroll down but reappears when i go back up..

Comment: you'd have to determine where in your implementation you'd want the element to switch positions, and style them accordingly from there. If you only want the master_footer to appear while you're at a certain scrolling point in the page, then set a range of scroll values and check the location on scroll.

Answer (score 1):

by changing only the js code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                    $("#reas").fadeIn(2000);
                    $(".footer").fadeIn(2000);
                    $(".master_footer").css("position", "relative");
                }else{
                    $(".master_footer").css("position", "absolute");
                }
            });
```

But i would rather use something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                        $("#reas").fadeIn(2000);
                        $(".footer").fadeIn(2000);
                        $(".master_footer").addClass('relative');
                    }else{
                        $(".master_footer").removeClass('relative');
                    }
                });
```

and then you can just custom your css

```
.relative{  position:relative; }
```

Comment: thats better but i still end up with the original problem.

Comment: i don't understand, can you create a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend a polling solution rather than attaching an event handler to the scroll event, particularly if you intend to support older versions of IE, some of which seem to trigger the event for each pixel scrolled!  E.g., you can check the scroll position as you are once per second.

Secondly, since you are using 2000ms fades, you should hold in a variable the state of the elements being faded so you don't fire a fadeOut event while the element is still being faded in (or at the very least you can `stop()` the existing animation).

And as far as your original question is concerned, it looks like maybe you should be able to set `$('.master_footer').css('position', 'absolute')` when (t < y) if you are setting position to relative when t == y.  (You also might want to check t >= y in case the browser being used supports overscroll).